# Loop within a loop not re-looping with reading a file Python3

Tags: python, file, loops

Trying to write a code that will find all of a certain type of character in a text file
For vowels it'll find all of the number of a's but won't reloop through text to read e's. help?

```
def finder_character(file_name,character):

    in_file = open(file_name, "r")

    if character=='vowel':
        brain_rat='aeiou'
    elif character=='consonant':
        brain_rat='bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    elif character=='space':
        brain_rat=''
    else:
        brain_rat='!@#$%^&*()_+=-123456789{}|":?><,./;[]\''       

    found=0 
    for line in in_file:
        for i in range (len(brain_rat)):
            found += finder(file_name,brain_rat[i+1,i+2])


    in_file.close()
    return found

def finder(file_name,character):
    in_file = open(file_name, "r")
    line_number = 1
    found=0
    for line in in_file:
        line=line.lower()
        found +=line.count(character)
    return found
```

Comment: def finder(file_name,character):
    in_file = open(file_name, "r")

    line_number = 1
    found=0
    for line in in_file:
        line=line.lower()
        found +=line.count(character)
    return found

Comment: Why does `finder_character` loop over `line in in_file` when you don't use `line`?

Comment: use line as in   line[:-1] ?

Comment: Is that supposed to answer my question?  Because it doesn't.

Comment: What do you intend `brain_rat[i+1,i+2]` to do?  This syntax is not legal for `list`s.

Comment: How do you use line, then?
We've mostly just been doing for-loops to go through all the lines and find stuff.

Comment: brain_rat[i+1,i+2] Just to go through the slices and tell me how many a's in the file, then go through the file again line by line and say how many e's....etc if it was looking for vowels.

Comment: @SandiWilliams I think you are over complicating what you are trying to do. Check my amended answer below that exaplins how to step through the file.

Comment: I'm getting errors with opts and defaults and some of the other notation that we haven't gone over in class.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It should do the trick. Regarding Lego's solution, I think that the default statement should be inside the curly brackets, like:

`opts = { 'vowel':'aeiou',
         'consonant':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz',
         'space':'', 
         default= '!@#$%^&*()_+=-123456789{}|":?><,./;[]\'' }`

Comment: That returns exactly what I was looking for. I'm heading off to class to ask my teacher about the generator, now.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I tried to explain the generator concept there. This is vital when dealing with large data in Python, so you should definitively try to understand it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your original code, you have to pass the filename to the `finder()` function, and open the file there, for each char you are testing for.

The reason for this is that the file object (`in_file`) is a generator, not a list. The way a generator works, is that it returns the next item each time you call their `next()` method. When you say

```
for line in in_file:
```

The `for ... in` statement calls `in_file.next()` as long as the `next()` method "returns" (it actually use the keyword `yield`, but don't think about that for now) a value. When the generator doesn't return any values any longer, we say that the generator is exhausted. You can't re-use an exhausted generator. If you want to start over again, you have to make a new generator.

I allowed myself to rewrite your code. This should give you the desired result. If anything is unclear, please ask!

```
def finder_character(file_name,character):

    with open(file_name, "r") as ifile:
        if character=='vowel':
            brain_rat='aeiou'
        elif character=='consonant':
            brain_rat='bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
        elif character=='space':
            brain_rat=' '
        else:
            brain_rat='!@#$%^&*()_+=-123456789{}|":?><,./;[]\'' 

    return sum(1 if c.lower() in brain_rat else 0 for c in ifile.read())
```

**test.txt:**

```
eeehhh
iii!#
kk ="k
oo o
```

**Output:**

```
>>>print(finder_character('test.txt', 'vowel'))
9
>>>print(finder_character('test.txt', 'consonant'))
6
>>>print(finder_character('test.txt', 'space'))
2
>>>print(finder_character('test.txt', ''))
4
```

If you are having problems understanding the `return` line, it should be read backwards, like this:

```
Sum this generator:
    Make a generator with values as v in:
        for row in ifile.read():
            if c.lower() in brain_rat:
                v = 1
            else:
                v = 0
```

If you want to know more about generators, I recommend the [Python Wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) concerning it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you are trying to do in `finder_character`. I'm not sure why you need `finder` at all.

In python you can loop over iterables (like strings), so you don't need to do `range(len(string))`.

```
for line in in_file:
    for i in brain_rat:
        if i in line: found += 1
```

There appear to be a few other oddities in your code too:

- You open (and iterate through) the file twice, but only closed once.
- `line_number` is never used
- You get the total of a character in a file for each line in the file, so the total will be vastly inflated.

This is probably a much safer version, `with open...` is generally better than `open()... file.close()` as you don't need to worry as much about error handling and closing. I've added some comments to help explain what you are trying to do.

```
def finder_character(file_name,character):
    found=0    # Initialise the counter
    with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
        # Open the file
        in_file = file_name.split('\n')

        opts = { 'vowel':'aeiou',
                 'consonant':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz',
                 'space':'' }
        default= '!@#$%^&*()_+=-123456789{}|":?><,./;[]\''

        for line in in_file:
            # Iterate through each line in the file
            for c in opts.get(character,default):
                With each line, also iterate through the set of chars to check.
                if c in line.lower():
                    # If the current character is in the line
                    found += 1  # iterate the counter.
    return found    # return the counter
```